# Log base in Cross Entropy Loss

Tags: loss-functions, logarithm, backpropagation, cross-entropy, log-loss

What is the base for the logarithm used in the cross entropy loss (while doing multiclass classification's backpropagation)? Is it e, 2, or 10?